# FileSystemException: Cannot open file (OS Error: Too many open files errno=24)

Tags: flutter, dart

I use several "Future.wait" with lists of Dio-request to fetch files on remote server at once and every Dio-request has a following operation like File().writeAsBytesSync() or File().writeAsBytes(), so maybe the concurrency is a bit massive, app throw 'FileSystemException: Cannot open file (OS Error: Too many open files errno=24)'.

Is there some awesome solution for this issue, or I can only have to construct some execution queue to do this?

Comment: Without a change of the program there is an option to increase the maximum number of open files on an operation system level. It depends on the operation system, though.

Comment: Can you delay your File instantiation until your dio response?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of packages on pub that let you queue operations and limit the number of concurrent executions.

[pool](https://pub.dev/packages/pool) is the most popular.
There's also [batcher](https://pub.dev/packages/batcher) and [concurrent_queue](https://pub.dev/packages/concurrent_queue).